# Combination Identifier

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to identify in one column those who are present in the data but there is limit to only 10 nests. Is there easier or some other way for me to get the result that I want?

[image: Code]

I hope you could help me.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using a CASE expression:

```
select a,b,c,d,
       case (a + b * 2 + c * 4 + d * 8)
          when 0 then 'none'
          when 1 then 'a'
          when 2 then 'b'
          when 4 then 'c'
          when 8 then 'd'
          when 3 then 'a-b'
          when 7 then 'a-b-c'
          when 5 then 'a-c'
          when 9 then 'a-d'
          when 6 then 'b-c'
          when 10 then 'b-d'
          when 14 then 'b-c-d'
          when 12 then 'c-d'
          when 15 then 'a-b-c-d'
          else 'error'
        end as present
from the_table;
```

This creates a "bitset" with one bit for each column, then tests for the values that uniquely identify each combination.

This assumes that there are no `NULL` values in those columns.

Online example on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6f0b05b5afd2e647db9f8ccd6acf077a)

---

Another option might be to concat expressions:

```
select concat(case when a = 1 then 'a-' end, 
              case when b = 1 then 'b-' end, 
              case when c = 1 then 'c-' end, 
              case when d = 1 then 'd-' end)
from the_table;
```

That leaves an ugly dangling `-` at the end, but you could probably remove that with a combination of `substring()` and/or `replace()` calls.